# List all users with ALL PRIVILEGES in MySQL

Tags: mysql, users, user-permissions

I need to find a way to list all database users that have `ALL PRIVILILEGES` on `*.*` (all databases and tables). Additionally, it would be great if it could also list only those with `GRANT OPTION`.

My initial thought was to `select User from mysql.user where` each privilege field is `="Y"`. That would result in a very long query. Is there another, more convenient way?

Answer (score 4):

On MariaDB there are a total of 28 grants:

```
SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE.
```

To show all users with all grants:

```
select count(*) as grants, grantee from information_schema.user_privileges group_by grantee having grants >= 28;
```

To check if it's true, you can check with result from

```
select * from information_schema.user_privileges;
```

and compare :)

Comment: Why the underscore in `group_by`?